# Pass value to CodeBehind function on anchor click

Tags: html, asp.net

I am trying to call a CodeBehind function, onClick, on an anchor HTML tag.

However, having this

```
<a onClick="function" CommandName="myValue" runat="server">my link</a>
```

I am not able to get the `myValue` variable

```
HyperLink btn = (HyperLink)(sender);
string yourValue = btn.CommandArgument;
```

Since `HyperLink` does not contain a definition for `CommandArgument`.

Any solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need a LinkButton for that to work with an `OnCommand`, not an `OnClick`.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" CommandName="myValue">my link</asp:LinkButton>
```

Code behind

```
protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string yourValue = e.CommandName.ToString();
}
```